# Trigger click() for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, there are a couple approaches to the problem of triggering a click() for a dynamically-generated element. First, this will work for Chrome but not IE or FF:

```
var href="/myUrl";
var link = $("<a>");
link.prop("href", href);
link[0].click()
```

So, if the thinking is that using click() on an element that doesn't exist won't work in IE or FF, what's the best approach?

```
var href="/myUrl";
var link = $("<a>");
link.prop("href", href);
$(document).append(link); // Attach it to the DOM so it exists
link[0].click()
```

Or is there something even simpler that I'm missing? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: If you're trying to redirect the page you don't need to create any elements and fake events, you can just do `window.location.assign('/myUrl');`

Comment: Not redirecting, just triggering download of a file.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yes, FF, too. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Same deal. Use `window.location.assign('url here')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Doesn't that muck up the address bar?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio - Delegated events is a potential solution, sure...but what's the inside of the anonymous function look like? e.target.click()

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Depends on the file type. If it's a binary file the browser should open the Save As dialog without actually changing the current location.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I thought I remembered it changing it regardless (on some browser, I don't recall which). But said memory could easily be from eight years ago. Things have...moved on a bit since then. :-)

Comment: @fumeng sorry - ignore my comment I thought you were asking how to attach an event handler to a dynamically-added element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a function that I've used in production code, it's a bit different from yours but it might be what you need.

```
function psuedoClick(href, target){
    if(!target) target = '_self';
    var falseAnchor = $('<a/>').attr({
        'href' : href,
        'target' : target
    }).appendTo('body');
    falseAnchor[0].click();
    falseAnchor.remove();
};
```

Just pass in the arguments when you call the function and it'll work.

Comment: I'm impressed that you can remove it immediately. I assumed you'd need at least a `setTimeout(..., 0)` around the removal. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

You've said you want to trigger the download of a file. Another simple way to do that is to have an invisible `iframe` on the page:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" style="display: none" id="downloader"></iframe>
```

...then when you want to trigger the download:

```
$("#downloader").attr("src", "/myUrl");
```

As with your current solution, it's important that the response containing the file have a `Content-Disposition` header identifying it as an "attachment" (the same header can also suggest a name), to get consistent handling across MIME types.